# What is the 'Liverpool Shuffle'?

Tags: playing-cards

Watching A Hard Days Night and they're playing cards in the train. Ringo shuffles the cards and someone (John?) says "Aye Aye, the liverpool shuffle" as Ringo doesn't actually shuffle the cards.

He splits the pack, riffles them (but the halves are a few inches apart), and then puts the two halves back together again.

Why is this called the Liverpool Shuffle?

Comment: Ringo... John... You're Paul... are you... --THE-- Paul?

Answer (score 3):

I think this is because Liverpudlians, especially back in the 60s, were stereotypically a bit cheeky (as in, untrustworthy).

John is saying that it's the usual Liverpool way of shuffling so as not to shuffle at all, and likely the cards will be stacked in Ringo's favour.

Comment: This is hilarious. Thanks for coming back with the answer.